# Ember-cli numeric input box

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I need an input box that can accept only numbers, does exist a component in ember-cli for this? I tried in vain with {{input type="number"}}

Comment: Try `pattern` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Ember validations addon https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations and then more specifically https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations#numericality

Essentially you'll be adding a validation like this:

```
age: {
      numericality: true
    }
```

To the value of your input box.

Comment: This is unlikely to do what the OP wants, since it won't kick in until validation is explictly called. He seems to want the input box itself to reject non-numeric input.